# Scraping difficult website - may be intentional

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

One of the data sources I have been trying to scrape has been proving elusive, which may be intentional on the data providers part as a way of pushing users onto their subscription service. This is the website below.

https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/255

It should link to NGX Fin FF,FP for AESO Flat (CA/MWh),Alberta and for Time Period: Current Settlement.

I can get it working for the same day, but once the day is over the scrape no longer works which has completely stumped me.

```
import datetime
import logging
import pandas as pd
import requests
import lxml
from datetime import date

import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest,volumeBlob: func.Out[bytes]):
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

if mytimer.past_due:
    logging.info('The timer is past due!')

logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)


cookies = {
    'JSESSIONID': '477F62CBEBC61CDFEEE9731813B1D538',
    'OptanonAlertBoxClosed': '2022-05-17T15:59:03.608Z',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.1094311247.1652803144',
    'iceBanner': 'rcDisclaimer',
    '_gcl_au': '1.1.195669816.1660653521',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.215733394.1661950999',
    'ICE_MARKETDATA': '1174809866.6426.0000',
    'OptanonConsent': 'isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Thu+Sep+01+2022+09%3A31%3A42+GMT-0600+(Mountain+Daylight+Time)&version=6.16.0&hosts=&consentId=76d26ec4-5ee0-408b-8380-9df9a3c10a8e&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0005%3A1%2CC0004%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0002%3A1&geolocation=%3B&AwaitingReconsent=false',
    'TS01fbe106': '013ade2eabdbfe5126fd8f2840815f288765427548e635980fd6984ed85b0b81b487f984c193676d29a538b9db33b64856b5418d25cd18f783ce2043dffa94a861829dc2fa',
}

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=477F62CBEBC61CDFEEE9731813B1D538; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2022-05-17T15:59:03.608Z; _ga=GA1.2.1094311247.1652803144; iceBanner=rcDisclaimer; _gcl_au=1.1.195669816.1660653521; _gid=GA1.2.215733394.1661950999; ICE_MARKETDATA=1174809866.6426.0000; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Thu+Sep+01+2022+09%3A31%3A42+GMT-0600+(Mountain+Daylight+Time)&version=6.16.0&hosts=&consentId=76d26ec4-5ee0-408b-8380-9df9a3c10a8e&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0005%3A1%2CC0004%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0002%3A1&geolocation=%3B&AwaitingReconsent=false; TS01fbe106=013ade2eabdbfe5126fd8f2840815f288765427548e635980fd6984ed85b0b81b487f984c193676d29a538b9db33b64856b5418d25cd18f783ce2043dffa94a861829dc2fa',
    'Origin': 'https://www.theice.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/255',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
}

data = 'reportId=255&group=Power&selectedMarket=NGX+Fin+FF%2C+FP+for+AESO+Flat%2C+(CA%2FMWh)%2C+Alberta&selectedTimePeriod=Current+Settlement&rcMode=2'

response = requests.post('https://www.theice.com/marketdata/public-web/ngx/daily-settlement-price/report', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)
df = dfs[0]
df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
df['BeginDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BeginDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])
df['days'] = df['EndDate'] - df['BeginDate']
df['days'] = df['days'].dt.days
df = df[(df['days'] > 1)]

df['BeginDate'] = df['BeginDate'].dt.date
df['EndDate'] = df['EndDate'].dt.date
df.set_index('BeginDate',inplace=True,drop=True)
pd.to_numeric(df["# Trades"],errors="ignore")
pd.to_numeric(df["TotalVolume"],errors="ignore")
pd.to_numeric(df["Open"],errors="ignore")
pd.to_numeric(df["High"],errors="ignore")
pd.to_numeric(df["Low"],errors="ignore")
pd.to_numeric(df["Settle"],errors="ignore")
pd.to_numeric(df["Net OI"],errors="ignore")
pd.to_numeric(df["days"],errors="ignore")
df['DateModified'] = date.today()
print(df)
volumeBlob.set(df.to_csv())
```

I have used a curl -> python to create the requests param and header body. Wondering if this is where I have gone wrong (and why?).
https://curlconverter.com/python

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't just use the same `JSESSIONID` for all eternity and expect it to work. It corresponds to a unique session, which is bound to expire at some point in time, at which point that session ID becomes invalid. I would suggest you make an initial request to some endpoint on that domain to start a session, and capture the cookies via `requests.Session` - then make all successive requests using that session object. That way you won't have to hardcode the session ID, along with all those other cookies.

Comment: @PaulM. Your comment made me laugh. I don't have a great grasp on this aspect of session ID, would just going to the homepage and getting that cookie as a variable be sufficient?

Comment: Haha sorry if it came off as a bit harsh. Going to the homepage to capture the session ID seems like it should work, though it looks like accessing the API is possible without many cookies/request headers, as the other answers have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas Dataframe and API, getting the following ResultSet

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
api_url = 'https://www.theice.com/marketdata/api/reports/all'
headers= {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    }

req=requests.get(api_url,headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(req)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
id                                               name  ... active recaptchaRequired
0    101                            Historical Daily Volume  ...   True              True
1    102                            Daily Settlement Prices  ...   True              True
2    104  Deliveries - Gasoil Delivery (LS Gasoil from F...  ...   True              True
3    284  Midland WTI American Gulf Coast Futures Settle...  ...   True              True
4    114                Preliminary Open Interest - Futures  ...   True              True
..   ...                                                ...  ...    ...               ...
125   96                  Historical Daily Volume - Futures  ...   True              True
126   97                  Historical Daily Volume - Options  ...   True              True
127   98                                Daily Volume and OI  ...   True              True
128   99                            Historical Daily Volume  ...   True              True
129  100                                Daily Volume and OI  ...   True              True

[130 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

To read the table to Panda's dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.theice.com/marketdata/public-web/ngx/daily-settlement-price/report"
data = {
    "reportId": "255",
    "group": "Power",
    "selectedMarket": "NGX Fin FF, FP for AESO Flat, (CA/MWh), Alberta",
    "selectedTimePeriod": "Current Settlement",
    "rcMode": "2",
}

df = pd.read_html(requests.post(url, data=data).text)[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                              Market   BeginDate     EndDate  # Trades  TotalVolume   Open   High    Low    Settle   Net OI
0    NGX Fin FF, FP for AESO Flat, (CA/MWh), Alberta  2022-08-01  2022-08-31         0            0    NaN    NaN    NaN  254.1346   951576
1    NGX Fin FF, FP for AESO Flat, (CA/MWh), Alberta  2022-08-30  2022-08-30         0            0    NaN    NaN    NaN  325.0000        0
2    NGX Fin FF, FP for AESO Flat, (CA/MWh), Alberta  2022-08-31  2022-08-31         0            0    NaN    NaN    NaN  450.0000        0
3    NGX Fin FF, FP for AESO Flat, (CA/MWh), Alberta  2022-09-01  2022-09-01         0            0    NaN    NaN    NaN  250.0000        0


...
```